# Installer for a .bin file that will run on Ubuntu

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I have a .bin file that will comprise of 3 files 
1. tar.gz file 
2. .zip file 
3. install.sh file

For now the install.sh file is empty. I am trying to write a shell script that should be able to extract the .zip file and copy the tar.gz file to a specific location when the *.bin file is executed on an Ubuntu machine. There is a Jenkins job that will pull in these 3 files to create the *.bin file

My Question is how do I access the tar.gz and .zip file from my shell script ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two general tricks that I'm aware of for this sort of thing.

The first is to use a file format that will ignore invalid data and find the correct file contents automatically (I believe `zip` is one such format/tool).

When this is the case you just run the tool on the packed/concatenated file and let the tool do its job.

For formats and tools where that doesn't work and/or isn't possible the general trick is to embed markers in the concatenated file such that the original script ignores the data but can operate on itself to "extract" the embedded data so the other tool can operate on the extracted contents.